# What is the best Twitter API wrapper/library for .NET?

Tags: .net, api, twitter

I'm looking for a way to programatically generate a twitter feed for a .NET application. Any recommendations as to a good wrapper for the twitter api to ease the work?

Boaz

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[TweetSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp/) looks like it should be a decent option as well.

Comment: i've been having tons of problems with this one so far...

Comment: Looks like the domain has gone with the wind.

Comment: Not just the domain, but the code on tweetsharp.codeplex.com and their Twitter account as well... sad, considering it was a decent library.

Comment: that is too bad.  What do you guys think I should do with this answer?  Delete it?  Leave it as-is?

Comment: Edit it, and say that the library is gone! =\ sad

Comment: good idea, i tried to delete it a while back, can't do that since it's the accepted answer.

Comment: TweetSharp's developer moved it from CodePlex to GitHub. I've updated the link for you. I'm not sure if it's still recommended to use that library, though...

Comment: For those still interested, looks like TweetSharp v2 has made it's way into NuGet, with version 2.1.3 last updated 2/20/2012.

Comment: This lib has no documentation!!!! OMG!!!

Comment: TweetSharp make his work, but is not follow Framework Design Guidlines especially on errors reporting. If some method will fail, you would get null result from method with no details! There is no exceptions!

Comment: Please avoid this framework - basically it seems broken.  It uses Int32 for IDs that are too big, so depending on the data, you get JSON parse exceptions.

Answer (score 20):

[Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter/) for authentication + custom C# code with [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) and [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Something like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authValue;
    var response = await client.GetAsync("search/tweets.json");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var tweets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweets>(json);
    }
}
```

Good read:

- [Extending HttpClient with OAuth to Access Twitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/henrikn/extending-httpclient-with-oauth-to-access-twitter) (Feb, 2012)
- [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)
- Official documentation: [OAuth API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/overview), [REST API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs), [Streaming API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs)

Comment: This is why I love REST APIs and hate SOAP

Comment: This is outdated information. As others have mentioned, Twitter has moved to the OAuth interface, which is many times more complex than what was needed in the past. Looks like you updated this reply to include a link to OAuth code, which ironically depends on an OAuth library on CodePlex. So much for not using an existing library.

Comment: Can you please describe what is the `authValue` used ?? I'm trying to use `verify_credentials.json` API and having lots of problem in figuring out how to use it (Reponse returned is always BadRequest)

Answer (score 9):

there is a linq to twitter project on codeplex:

http://www.codeplex.com/LinqToTwitter

Besides the [Yedda library](http://devblog.yedda.com/index.php/2007/05/16/twitter-c-library/), you can read Pedro Santos' [blog](http://psantos-blog.zi-yu.com/?p=197) on his experience.

Comment: is this linq to twitter workable on asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 8):

[Here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) is a list of all the libraries listed on twitter's website.

[Here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) is a link to Twitter's REST API documentation.

[Here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis) is a link to Twitters Streaming API documentation

Comment: Library link has changed to: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries

Answer (score 7):

You'll find an updated list of .NET Twitter libraries on Twitter's developer site:

**[Twitter Developers: Twitter Libraries (for .NET)](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet)**

- DotNetOpenAuth by Andrew Arnott – an OpenID, OAuth and InfoCard library
- Hammock by Daniel Crena – an HTTP API client supporting OAuth authentication.
- LINQ to Twitter by Joe Mayo – a LINQ provider for the Twitter API
- OAuth-Dot-Net by Chris – an OAuth library for clients and providers
- TweetSharp by Daniel Crenna & Jason Diller – a Twitter API library built with Hammock
- Twitterizer by DigitallyBorn – a Twitter API library (requires .NET > 3.5)
- TwitterVB by Duane Roelands – a VB.NET Twitter API library

Answer (score 4):

All good answers, LinqToTwitter good.  Also check out my post explaining the basics of using the Twitter API from C#/LINQ, including being aware of rate limits.  (Which is important to understand).

http://stuff.seans.com/2009/04/04/a-simple-net-twitter-api-wrapper-using-linq/

Coming soon - a version of my code that automatically adjusts request speed to your rate limit.  (Which is either 100/hr by default, or 20,000/hr if you or your site is "white listed").

Answer (score 3):

Twitterizer looks like it may be worth a look - it's even open source now... http://www.twitterizer.net/

Comment: Not the best option at all. With new Twitter features (like entities) and other stuff, it falls down. Not reliable for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [Twitteroo](http://rareedge.com/twitteroo/blog/2007/02/10/twitteroo-13-released/). But Yedda is better. I have a hobby Twitter client project which looks like Google Talk (named jata). It ca be found [here](http://www.codeplex.com/jata) in codeplex if you are interested.