# upload a tweet using C#

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best Twitter API wrapper/library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685015/what-is-the-best-twitter-api-wrapper-library-for-net)

My boss wants to make periodic updates to the company twitter account but doesn't really want to mess with it through the web or follow others.

I'm sure there is plenty of info but I thought I would start out by asking the experts

is there a twitter class or dll that I can use to do simple posting via twitter?

(similar to the flicker.net librarby?)

Comment: So he wants you to build a Twitter client because he doesn't want to open his web browser...?

Comment: LOL - lazy bosses FTW. Just open a web browser.

Comment: It's not really lazy...how long could it take to open a web browser?  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: It sounds like a prime example of wasting developer time.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't want to mess with it through the web"?  www.twitter.com and it takes you straight to your twitter page with a giant text box for you to enter your tweets. [Assuming youve opted to stay signed in].

"...or follow others".  Then he doesn't have to...  Choosing not to follow someone via the website or via a homebrew application amounts to the same thing really.

I think your boss just wants a shiny new toy...

Good luck :)

Comment: This is awfully close to printing out your boss' emails for him, and typing in his hand-written replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [tweetsharp.com](http://tweetsharp.com/) - sounds like it could be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Start reading about the [Twitter REST API Method: statuses/update](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses%C2%A0update). All you need to do is formulate the proper WebRequests (one for authentication, one for the update).

> Updates the authenticating user's
>   status.  Requires the status parameter
>   specified below.  Request must be a
>   POST.  A status update with text
>   identical to the authenticating user's
>   current status will be ignored to
>   prevent duplicates.

Something along the lines of:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

Answer (score -2):

Tweet from the PowerShell commmand-line it doesn't get any simpler [than this](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2008/12/30/introducing-poshtweet---the-powershell-twitter-script-library.aspx).