# How using the twitter api in visual studio c#

Tags: twitter

I'm working on a `C#` project the objectife this project to get all the tweets of a country
 with the **twitter api**, how to use the twitter API with  `C#`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685015/what-is-the-best-twitter-api-wrapper-library-for-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a specific option for a country, but you might come close by using the geocode parameter. Here's an example, using LINQ to TWitter:

```
        var srch =
            (from search in twitterCtx.Search
             where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                   search.Query == "Twitter" &&
                   search.GeoCode == "37.781157,-122.398720,1mi"
             select search)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine("\nQuery: {0}\n", srch.SearchMetaData.Query);
        srch.Statuses.ForEach(entry =>
            Console.WriteLine(
                "ID: {0, -15}, Source: {1}\nContent: {2}\n",
                entry.StatusID, entry.Source, entry.Text));
```